# Usage of the term Q.E.F.

Tags: terminology

While researching the term Q.E.D last night, the phrase Q.E.F was mentioned, which was apparently "used by Euclid to indicate the end of the justification of a construction".

Does Q.E.F indicate the construction can be totally described given the information given above?

Or is it simply something like the period at the end of a sentence: "this is all I'm going to say about the construction at this time"?

http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI1.html

Comment: [Quod erat faciendum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.#QEF) "What was to make/be done".

Comment: It's just a phrase, so it should be used where appropriate. One "makes" or "does" a construction, and "proves" or "demonstrates" a theorem. So, QEF when a construction is finished, and QED when a proof is finished.

Comment: The linked article seems to give a pretty good description... "The Q.E.F. at the end of the proof is an abbreviation for the Latin words quod erat faciendum which means “which was to be done.” A few of the propositions, as this one and the next two, solve problems by constructions. These are the ones that end with Q.E.F."

Comment: I doubt greatly Euclides used a latin phrase to end his proofs....

Comment: When Euclid lived, the Romans were still a fairly minor Italian tribe.